# Web Deploy - move from port 80

Tags: iis, webdeploy

I have installed 'Web Deploy' on Windows Server 2012.

However it is listening on port 80 (I know this because there is a hardware firewall blocking 8172 and I can still deploy to it).

I have seen a way to do this with the command line - but applying to IIS 6 and using an msi file (I have a .exe for Web Deploy 3.5).
[Can the web deploy agent run on a port other than 80 on IIS6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867392/can-the-web-deploy-agent-run-on-a-port-other-than-80-on-iis6)

(I don't want web deploy to be available on port 80 for security reasons - when I use port 8172 I will be using a VPN to get through the firewall).

In 'Management Service' in IIS it states 8172 already not 80.

How can I stop it using port 80 - and make it use 8172 only?

thx

Comment: Have you checked out HttpNamespaceManager? https://github.com/iansrobinson/hydras-and-hypermedia/tree/master/tools/httpnamespacemanager

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx

Comment: Thanks can you elaborate?